# Extracting XML tags and values from CLOB data in a table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

One of my tables has a CLOB column with data as shown in the picture:

[image: data]

Please help me with a query which results the number of rows which contain the `<location>` tag.

Comment: Please [post text rather than images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). It would also be helpful to include your current query attempt, what is wrong with it (error/wrong results), and what you actually expect to see for your sample data. A larger sample would probably be useful in this case too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the `clob` to `xmltype` using `xmltype.createxml()`. With `existsnode()` you can then check, if there is a `location` node. Use `count()` to get the number of matching records.

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM elbat
       WHERE existsnode(xmltype.createxml(nmuloc), '//location') > 0;
```